# Why this code is not working - sass

Tags: css, node-sass

This is working perfectly:

```
.navbar_ind {
  background-color: blue;
}
.navbar_ind .nav-link:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

but when I am doing like this it does not work, why?

```
.navbar_ind {
 background-color: blue;
&__nav-link:hover {
  color: red;
}
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at your SCSS output? Currently it's `.navbar_ind__nav-link:hover` because of your incorrect use of `&`, which in this case extends the class name. You want to write `& .nav-link:hover`.

Comment: because with the SASS code you willl have this selector `.navbar_ind__nav-link:hover`

Answer (score 3):

You can use & with space ou not use it at all, like this:

```
.navbar_ind {
 background-color: blue;
& .nav-link:hover {
  color: red;
}
}
```

Or like this:

```
.navbar_ind {
 background-color: blue;
.nav-link:hover {
  color: red;
}
}
```

Both should work fine

Comment: `You can use & with space ou not use it at all` this a bit confusion as we may understand from it that we need to always use space with & ... but it's not correct

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
.navbar_ind {
    background-color: blue;

    &__nav-link:hover {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

will compile to:

```
.navbar_ind {
    background-color: blue;    
}
.navbar_ind__nav-link:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

What you need is:

```
.navbar_ind {
    background-color: blue;
    // The ampersand selector isn't even needed.
    & .nav-link:hover {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup as said in the comment. Some people actually like to keep it so, both are fine.

Answer (score 1):

**You are using '&' selector the wrong way.** It is not needed for child selectors.

The equivalent SASS for the CSS

```
.navbar_ind {
  background-color: blue;
}
.navbar_ind .nav-link:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

is

```
.navbar_ind {
 background-color: blue;
  .nav-link:hover {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

The equivalent SASS for the CSS

```
.navbar_ind {
  background-color: blue;
}
.navbar_ind.nav-link:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

is

```
.navbar_ind {
 background-color: blue;
  &.nav-link:hover {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

**[Read more](https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/) about the & selector.**